# simple python tensorflow InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes

Tags: python, tensorflow

Simple model and 1 row of data, I think any recent version of python and tensorflow, returns:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes.
```

https://github.com/jasonsackett/tferrorgeab

I have searched high and low and tried so many things, but something simple is breaking this and the error message is not helping me very much.

Run with:

python mlturn1a1ssa.py

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: hardcoding the data in this line:

`g.train_data = dfin.values`

to this instead makes it run:

`g.train_data = np.array([[0]*4])`

so it is something with the dataframe .values transformation, 
 even though the data looks ok when printed.

Comment: UPDATE 2:

This simplified example did not exactly reflect my local issue, dropping columns like this does fix it (code is updated):

`g.train_data = dfin.drop(columns=['ctags', 'ltags', 't']).values`

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the str to unicode, here is the example

```
df=pd.read_csv('test.csv',encoding='utf-8')
reviews = df['review'].values.astype('U')
```